# How can it be that all closures implement "FnOnce"?

Tags: rust, closures

I read [chapter 13.01](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) of the Rust Book and there is this section that confuses me greatly. Excerpt (emphasis mine):

> `FnOnce` consumes the variables it captures from its enclosing scope, known as the closure’s environment. To consume the captured variables, the closure must take ownership of these variables and move them into the closure when it is defined. The `Once` part of the name represents the fact that **the closure can’t take ownership of the same variables more than once, so it can be called only once.**
>
> When you create a closure, Rust infers which trait to use based on how the closure uses the values from the environment. **All closures implement `FnOnce` because they can all be called at least once.** Closures that don’t move the captured variables also implement `FnMut`, and closures that don’t need mutable access to the captured variables also implement

Don't the highlighted sentences contradict one another? If `Fn` and `FnMut` closures can be called *more* than once, why do they inherit from `FnOnce`?

I understand how each trait works individually - it's this superposition of `FnOnce` plus {`FnMut`, `Fn`} that bugs me. Why haven't the `FnMut` and `Fn` traits been defined independently of `FnOnce`?

I read GitHub [issue #1225](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1255) but that didn't clear up my confusion.

Comment: If I accept a closure that I **will** only call once, but you give me a closure that **could** be called multiple times, would you want that to compile? That's the reason.

Comment: One should twist the reasoning the other way around: traits provide _added_ behavior. If a type implements `FnOnce`, then a value of that type can be called like a function, once. `Fn` and `FnMut` _extend_ this capability, letting the value be called multiple times.

Comment: Whoah, thinking about this in terms of "added behaviour" makes a lot of sense. Thanks @E_net4downvoteseverything!

Comment: The "twisting" also has to do with which perspective you are coming from. Do you think of the closure _implementing_ the trait or the item _receiving_ the trait?

Comment: @Shepmaster I was thinking in terms of the former perspective, but now I like the latter more.